# Saving a text input to separate js files

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a quiz web app with javascript and I am stuck.
There are 2 HTML files, one as **starter.html** and one as **index.html**. I have an input in my starter file which takes in a *username* which I want to display later on the index site like:

```
alert(`Congrats ${playerName} you got all the questions right!`)
```

and a "submit" link which takes you to the next site and stores a variable like this:

```
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
<a id="startGame" href="index.html">Start Game</a>

const inputArea = document.querySelector("#username");
const startButton = document.querySelector("#startGame");

var saveUsername = function () {
  var playerName = inputArea.value;
};
```

How can i access the playerName variable from the **index.html**? Firstly, I intended to use a global js file but I miss some declared elements since i have two separate html file and it does not find the elements during the DOM manipulation (cannot read properties of null). I tried using two separate js file but I couldn't find the solution to access data from a javascript file and store it in the second one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` for that purpose. When a user enters his / her name in the textbox you can save the value to `localStorgae` and fetch the value on the index page.

```js
const usernameInputField = document.querySelector('#username'),
  button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (usernameInputField.value != "") {
    localStorage.setItem('user', usernameInputField.value);
  }
  alert('Username Saved Successfully. Starting the game...');
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your name" />
<button>Start Game</button>
```

and to get the value back, simply use

```
if(localStorage.getItem != null && localStorage.getItem('user') != "") {
   console.log(localStorage.getItem('user'));
   // here you can set the name as innerText of some element
}
```

You can check this out here https://jsfiddle.net/za01kp46/

Comment: Thank you so much! I am currently in the middle of a JS course at somewhere 30hrs but I did not know about localStorage. It solved my problem though, thank you again.

Comment: you can also do something like `href="index.html?user=john"` and then use `searchParams` to get the username. But this is not suggested as the value can be easily changed